# how to declare wildcard in namespaces in soapui?

Tags: xpath, namespaces, soapui, wildcard

I have two environments. Local and cloud. in cloud i get result with namespace as

```
<ServiceAvailability **xmlns="http://types.infrastructure.abc.de"**>
  <BackendSystem>*</BackendSystem>
  <BackendName>Domain Server Release GIT commit hash</BackendName>
  <Status>OK</Status>
  <URL>*</URL>
  <Timestamp>*</Timestamp>
</ServiceAvailability>
```

and locally i get without namespace

```
<ServiceAvailability>
  <BackendSystem>*</BackendSystem>
  <BackendName>Domain Server Release GIT commit hash</BackendName>
  <Status>OK</Status>
  <URL>*</URL>
  <Timestamp>*</Timestamp>
</ServiceAvailability>
```

I am using xpath in soapui as

```
declare namespace ns1='http://types.infrastructure.abc.de';
/ns1:ServiceAvailabilities/ns1:ServiceAvailability[ns1:BackendName='Domain Server Release GIT commit hash']
```

so it passes for cloud but not locally because there is namespace. So how can I make my testcase generic that involves * as namespace (basically ignore namespace) There is as option in soapui that says **ignore namespace  prefixes** but when ticked still it doesnt work ???  How can i use wildcards in my namespace declaration???

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle it is to use local names instead. So the following should work for both versions of the xml in your question:

```
//*[local-name()='ServiceAvailability']/*[local-name()="BackendName"['Domain Server Release GIT commit hash']]
```

Comment: actually i have many ServiceAvailability elements inside single ServiceAvailabilities so im getting "more than one match in given reponse"

Comment: @MiGo Well, I can only work with the xml samples in the question, not w/ real life :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help you, this **groovy** code works with or without namespace for soapui.

[image]

I ran the same code with 2 different responses,

onlly thing you need to change in below code is  "REST_Request" <-- the name of your teststep

```
 def GroovyUtils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
 def request=GroovyUtils.getXmlHolder("REST_Request#Response")
 def backendName = request.getNodeValue("/*:ServiceAvailability/*:BackendName")
 log.info backendName
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use a wildcard namespace, you would use the asterisk `*` in place of the namespace. So for your example, it would be:

```
/*:ServiceAvailabilities/*:ServiceAvailability[*:BackendName='Domain Server Release GIT commit hash']
```

Notice there is no `declare` statement!